# publicly hosted image with a liberal CORS policy?

Tags: html, image, canvas, cors

I am doing some testing on loading images into canvas, and am using a *privately* hosted image on our aws cdn.  This cdn has a CORS policy which lets me load the image into the canvas.

I would like to *publicly* share my code with the world via github, jsbin, etc., but need to host an image or two with a liberal CORS policy.  Is there an image out there which I could use?  Google and Google Image search are not turning anything up.

Comment: This has CORS... the images are random... but it's fine as a sample https://picsum.photos/200/300

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I usually use http://imgur.com/ for images (same site as SO uses for their inline images) - no sign up required, just upload or paste in an image link and you're ready to go.

It support CORS requirement so you can link directly and use it with canvas for pixel extraction.

If you need to host different files in addition to image I would suggest DropBox as markE does.

There are restriction however, as with any free service incl. ImgUr and DropBox, so be sure to read the Terms (ToS) of use before using the links (ie. none of them intent to function as a CDN so you might want to check out some commercial CDN providers).

## Enabling CORS usage

If allowed you can do this in JavaScript - set crossOrigin before setting src:

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";  // or "anonymous", will be interpreted the same
...
img.src = "...";
```

As attribute for HTML tag (order doesn't matter):

```
<img crossOrigin="" src="" ...>
```

## Test

```js
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = test;
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg";

function test() {

  var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // This will fail if no CORS support, otherwise all OK
  try {
    ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 10, 10);
    alert("All OK");
  } 
  catch(err) {
    alert("No CORS support...");
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: imgur is blocking my images with: `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Comment: @AgentZebra seem to work fine... (see added test), Make sure you use crossOrigin property/attribute correctly. If you're sure you do, check console log/network tab to see error message.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks. I was trying to pull images into a pixi js file with this. `var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://imgur.com/SmYfo2m");` How would I set the crossOrigin property/attribute in this situation?

Comment: @AgentZebra just use `PIXI.Texture.fromImage(url, true);` (ref. http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Texture.html#.fromImage). Also remember to use imgurl link with the extension (.jpg, .png etc.) The link in the example goes to a page, not the image itself. A small but important detail : `PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://i.imgur.com/SmYfo2m.jpg", true);`

Comment: Oh, duh. haha. Thank you @K3N - big help.

Comment: Apparently I had to sign up to imgur, only then my images became CORS enabled.

Comment: I am trying to load an Imgur image with XmlHttpRequest and I am getting error 403 :(

Comment: @IvanKuckir for XMLHttpRequest, see [this page](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/), or try loading with [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead and define cors type in option.

Comment: @epistemex, Did you sign up to Imgur  ?

Answer (score 0):

Open up an account on dropbox.com.

Put a few images that you have rights to in your public folder.

The dropbox public folder hosts image in a CORS compliant way, so they are publicly sharable.

You can get the sharable link to an image in your public by right clicking on that image.

Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: I've tried this approach and am getting: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0vxg01b9qlrb4q/20130512_180852.jpg?dl=0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.` Perhaps things changed since 2013

Comment: @ValRedchenko. Yes, Dropbox "public" folders are no longer sharable,  although they do offer sharable folders for a fee -- shame on you Dropbox!

Comment: I can't guarantee how long this link will stay valid for (it's from someone's Plunker) but this link to a CORS-enabled image might be helpful to someone: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kienzle.geschaeft/yellow_MarkerA.png